# Why do I keep getting 405 method on jquery ajax post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I keep getting 405 method not allowed

```
$("#username").bind("keyup",function()
   {

     let a_dictionary = {"a": "test"};
      $.ajax("/test", {

        async:true,
        dataType: "text",
        type:"POST",
        data:a_dictionary,
        success: $("#paragraph").html("success"),
        error: $("#paragraph").html("error"),


      });
   });
```

I'm trying to send the a_dictionary dictionary to /test

`error: $("#paragraph").html("error"),`
keeps working

Comment: It seems that your back-end application does not accept POST request to the endpoint "/test", can you provide more information on how is your back-end coded?

Comment: Yes this was exactly the answer if you post that response in "ANSWER YOUR QUESTION" i will mark as resolved :)

also is there a way without using jquery extra points for that ;)